# Xiang-affected Mandarin: 元 read, gen?

Tags: pronunciation

Watching this YouTube video: [20121114 03 湖南 湖南一男子下班开滑翔伞回家 笑言空中无红灯](https://youtu.be/jPQ4zPjV2gQ?t=70)
@ ~1:10 the reporter says, what sounds to me like:

> 滑翔伞只要两万余元(gen)

then a second later he goes on:

> 加上动力机器只要六万余元(gen)

---

Looking at the Wiki page for [湘语](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B9%98%E8%AF%AD) it does note that:

> 元 ŋuĩ

The pronunciation of 元 in Xiang has an ŋ inital.

---

Is this just a mishap mashup of:

- Initial ŋ from Xiang 元
- Final uan from, attempted, MSM 元

That results in a gen sounding pronunciation for 元? Seems plausible to me.

Is this a feature of Xiang pidgin, 湘普, (the mix of Xiang and MSM)?

Comment: The reporter's y sounds like [ʝ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_palatal_fricative) or [ɟ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_palatal_plosive) to me, not /g/

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but I have noticed exactly the same pronunciation before, but I'm not sure exactly where, except that it was a Taiwanese news broadcast. My guess is that it's a personal idiosyncrasy of some kind rather than an accent, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is the standard mandarin pronunciation, possibly, you hear (?yuen), misheard this as gen.

Answer (score 0):

The pronunciation of "gen" is similar to "跟" and "根", but the author says "yuan" = 元.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is offered for information only.

[image]